# Best practices with hosting many static files

Tags: java, file, web-applications

Sometimes we have to keep very many small files in our project (e.g. isomorphic's smart client). it's about 10k small files. there is a problem with svn (i don't know how git handles it), copying, packaging, etc. but those files will almost never change as it's just an external library. is there any way to keep them in a single zip file and tell tomcat to host them from inside that file? Or they should be handled differently? Any best practices?

To be more precise. That's my folder structure:

```
src/main/
     +---webapp/
     |      +---static/    <-- thousand 3rd party's files in this dir
     |
     +---java/
```

Maven will build war with my code and static files and it will work. but it's a PINA to work with so many files before the war is built. i would like sth like:

```
src/main/
     +---webapp/
     |      +---static.zip    <-- only 1 file
     |
     +---java/
```

Is it possible on popular web servers?

Comment: maybe use a war file?

Comment: i have to build war file that contains those files and my application. i must do it every time i change my code. and i don't want to have those files on my disk, IDE etc

Comment: A war file is not the solution, but a jar. If this doesn't fit for you, please give further explanation about the problem **in your question** (not in comments).

Comment: You could use [maven war overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) to package the static resources into an overlay which will be combined with your other code when the war is built. This allows you to move the resources out of you main development repository and IDE.

Comment: but that means i can't do jetty:run and test it locally?

Comment: symlinks? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: The maven jetty plugin supports overlaid wars, see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#using-overlaid-wars)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a servlet-3.0 web application, create a jar file and put all your static resources under META-INF/resources in this jar file. Then place this jar file in WEB-INF/lib in the web application, and the container will serve your static resources as if they were at the root of the webapp.

So if you want the URL to the static resource foo.hml to be

```
http://localhost/myWebApp/static/foo.html,
```

you should have this directory/jar structure:

```
webapp
  WEB-INF
    lib
      static.jar
        META-INF
          resources
            static
              foo.html
```